# Trouble with fzf, stdin and invoking a program from rust:

Tags: shell, vim, rust, stdin, fzf

I have this very strange behavior occurring when I try to `fzf | myprogram`, `myprogram` in turn invokes `vim`. By the time `vim` is launched something has gone awry with `stty` settings. I'm able to reproduce this across, zsh & bash, config & no config, linux & macOS. The minimal repro:

```
cargo new myprogram
```

*src/main.rs*

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut file_name = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut file_name)
        .expect("Failed to read from stdin");
    file_name.retain(|c| !c.is_whitespace());

    println!("{}", file_name);
    std::process::Command::new("/bin/bash")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg(format!("vim {}", file_name))
        .spawn()
        .expect("Error: Failed to run editor")
        .wait()
        .unwrap()
        .success();
}
```

for convenience I generally: `cargo install --path .`

when I `fzf | myprogram` I'm able to select a file and it does open in `vim`, as expected. But in `insert` mode when I backspace I see: `^?`. When I exit vim and `^C` it doesn't work it simply inserts `^C` characters. Each newline is improperly formatted and is generally hard to read any output.

After a bit of research I came across the `reset` command. When I call `reset` it outputs the same thing in every test situation:

*reset*

```
Erase set to delete.
Kill set to control-U (^U).
Interrupt set to control-C (^C).
```

I've tried a handful of ways to read from `stdin` and invoke `vim` but this issue seems to persist.

What is going on?

Comment: To me this looks more like an issue with piping from fzf (and starting a curses-style program while fzf might still be active) than an issue with rust. You should try to convert your test case to e.g. C or Go (something fast in case this is a race issue and e.g. python would delay things enough the race would not occur) and see if you can still hit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Masklinn Inspired me to create an example where I just use `cat` and `xargs` and to my surprise that didn't work either!

I then came across [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why) which explains that vim modifies the current terminal when it starts, and when it's closing it tries to restore the configuration it had when it started. Except when it's invoked in a non-standard way it doesn't restore to the right thing.

All my problems were fixed by telling rust to launch vim like:

```sh
bash -c '</dev/tty vim "$@"'
```

instead of like:

```
bash -c 'vim "$@"'
```